# How to create Gaussian kernel and use it as filter in opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am developing road line detection algorithm with OpenCv and found some quote and I can't understand its fragment.

Could you explain it how would i achieve such thing in OpenCv?

Here is the quote:

> The image is then ﬁltered by a two dimensional Gaussian kernel. The vertical direction is a smoothing Gaussian, whose σy is adjusted according to the required height of lane segment (set to the equivalent of 1m in the image). The horizontal direction is a second-derivative of Gaussian, whose σx is adjusted according to the expected width of the lane.

How can i prepare such kernel? getDerivKernel doesn't seem to allow me to set its σx or σy.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe OpenCV has a function to do exactly this.

```
 Mat getGaussianKernel(int ksize, double sigma, int ktype=CV_64F)
```

see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html

Comment: Can I ask what is the correct way to access data in the resulting Mat object?
I tried `ptr<double>(0)[i] ` but got compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`GaussianBlur`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#GaussianBlur%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Size,%20double,%20double%29) method. From documentation:

> sigmaX - Gaussian kernel standard deviation in X direction.
>
> sigmaY -
>   Gaussian kernel standard deviation in Y direction; if sigmaY is zero,
>   it is set to be equal to sigmaX, if both sigmas are zeros, they are
>   computed from ksize.width and ksize.height, respectively (see
>   "getGaussianKernel" for details); to fully control the result
>   regardless of possible future modifications of all this semantics, it
>   is recommended to specify all of ksize, sigmaX, and sigmaY.

Comment: But GaussianBlur doesn't allow me to specify Y direction to be filtered with second-derivative of Gaussian.